# elements in viewport of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, viewport

I'm building a menu(unordered list) in Jquery that scrolls on click to a certain position. I want the elements that move out of the viewport to be placed at the beginning, so the menu items are always visible.

I have a menu:

```
<div id="work_overview">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link" class="imgs_work"><img /></a></li>
        <li><a href="link" class="imgs_work"><img /></a></li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

If have a script that moves the menu:

```
$('.imgs_work').click(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position('left');

    $('#work_overview ul').animate({ left:pos.left },1500);
});
```

I want the '#work_overview ul li' to be placed at the first position when leaving viewport, and I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you add more details ? HTML, and if possible a jsFiddle, because I don't understand your problem with just some words !

Comment: I think you have to change position to relative instead of absolute

Comment: I've updated the code, I hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

OK, I get it, so another try :

I propose you to use jQuery.prevAll() to retrieve the element before the clicked `<li>` and move it in the DOM.

An example here, without the animation : http://jsfiddle.net/C9LNf/

So, there is still a problem with your specific need. If I have it right, you want to move the `<li>` when only when it is out the container.

I have no idea how to do this simply. You could watch on `<li>` css property and detect when left position is too left, but there is no native jQuery function to achieve this. There is some ideas with timeouts [here](http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/), but I think it's like a bulldozer your tiny problem.

Another approach could be to split your animation in multiple ones, on for each li. You animate the whole thing, you move the element in the DOM, and you do the next animation.

Comment: Well, this is very useful information, thank you very much. I'm gonna trie again with this new information.. I was thinking, that I could start a custom event on animate start that checks the position of the '<li>', and stop the event with the callback of the animate function?

Answer (score 0):

This similar question was recently answered in partial on another discussion. What you will have to do, is use that method that I will post, and then modify it, to work that if the last item's index in view leaves the view port, remove it, and either use .prepend(), or insert it into html using the index function at index 1.

for example:

```
var itemToMoveToPosition1 = $('item');
$('li:(0)').html(itemToMoveToPisition1);
```

Something of that sort. As for the first part of your question, you need to compare some positions. If an element is scrollable, it has a scrollTop property, and scrollHeight property. THis is the full content height of the element that it has until it scrolls to the end. Different from the height property. So you need to compare when the element you are tracking is at a position greater then the height, but less then the scroll height. That means it is out of view. If you need an example, that further explains this, let me know, and I can post a jFiddle for you. Hopefully this helps.